# Need to mention a role

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I'm new to coding Discord bots in Python, so I need a little help with something.

I've created a support ticket system, which pings the creator, but it won't ping the @Moderator role.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```py
@nextcord.ui.button(
        label="Create Ticket.", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="create_ticket"
    )
    async def create_ticket(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
       msg = await interaction.response.send_message("A ticket is being created.", ephemeral=True)
       overwrites = {
           interaction.guild.default_role: nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
           interaction.guild.me: nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
           interaction.guild.get_role(1155548726715232299): nextcord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
       }
       channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(f"SupportTicket",
       overwrites=overwrites)
       await msg.edit(f"Channel created successfully! {channel.mention}")
       await channel.send(f"Thank you for opening a ticket, {interaction.user.mention}. A @Moderator will be with you as soon as possible. In the mean times, please provide a brief explanation as to what you need support with. @mention any user to add them to the ticket, but don't add offenders to the ticket, unless we ask for you to, please.", view=TicketSettings(), allowed_mentions=nextcord.AllowedMentions(roles=True))
```

Comment: Simply mention it with `<@&ROLE_ID>` instead.